# IE Permissions required for ActiveX controls

Tags: internet-explorer, com, permissions, internet-explorer-9, activex

I have a HTML+JS page which invokes an ActiveX control with the following code

```
<object id="somecomp" type="application/x-somecomps-associated-mime-type">
</object>
```

There is javascript which calls a method on the ActiveX using the following code

```
var myObj = document.getElementById('somecomp');
ret = myObj.somemethod(strInput);
```

If host this page on my local desktop `c:\something\my.html`, & open this page on IE9, I get a warning

```
Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts 
or ActiveX controls
```

There is also a button which says `[ Allow Blocked content]`. If I click on this button the active runs fine.

However if I host this page on a remote IIS server and open the page as `http://some_ip_address/my.html`, then I don't get this warning at all & the control doesn't get initialized. (`myObj` is not null - but when `somemethod` is called, IE crashes)

If I put `http://ipaddress` in my trusted sites, then I don't get the warning and the activex works fine.

Now I need to get this working even if the site is in the Internet Zone (i.e. not in trusted sites). There are a lot of ActiveX related Security settings in IE9. Is there an easy way to figure out which is the one I need to tweak - rather than trying it one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. The exact setting depends on whether the ActiveX Control is marked as safe for scripting or not, you'd still need to play with both sets to figure this out. Also, the control may be smart enough to check the security zone it's running from, and limit itself to only specific zones (e.g., Local or Trusted), or even to specific domain/sites. In such case, you'd have to add your web site (or URL) to that specific zone, but you might still be out of luck if the control is [domain-bound](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2007/09/18/developing-safer-activex-controls-using-the-sitelock-template.aspx).

[image]

Comment: Changing those disabled permissions to Prompt didn't help. I had to disable protected mode to get it working. Is there something more granular, I can do.

Comment: Could you give more info about the control itself? Have you tried creating it as `new ActiveXObject(progId)`?